# Downloading Qt with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw, qt5

I am trying to download Qt with MinGW from the following :

URL : http://qt-project.org/downloads

Link : Qt 5.2.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 634 MB)  (Info)

But it is extremely slow.

Can someone please suggest a better place to download the same stuff.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a mirror close to your place:

http://download.qt-project.org/static/mirrorlist/